# To remove the second last character from a string

Tags: awk, sed

I've a string something like this: `abdh0chjkj0g`.
I want to delete the second last character only if it is a `0`.

Comment: Should all zeros be removed from `rcaoe0aoea0o` and all `B` from `aoBoaeBo`? or is only the second to last character or zeros in general?

Comment: Hi, Only the 'zero' present in the second last position needs to be removed. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ echo 'abdhchjkj0g' | sed 's/0\(.\)$/\1/'
```

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo 'abdhchjkj0g' | perl -pe 's/0(?=.$)//'
```

Using [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu)[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ echo 'abdhchjkj0g' | awk '{print gensub(/0(.)$/, "\\1", "1")}'
```

```
abdhchjkjg
```

Comment: I don't think this quite does what is asked for yet (I think because the example doesn't match the question) - you'll need to pull all `0`s to match the question. For example, I think, `dsgf0dsfads0d0d` would need to become `dsgfdsfadsdd`

Comment: OP says : _the second last character_

Comment: Then continues to say "from the string everytime it appears"

Comment: And, as far as I can interpret his comment, only if it is a zero.

Comment: @cunninghamp3 Possibly with the qualifier "at that position". Note "everytime", not "everywhere".

Comment: Yeah - I've submitted an edit per OP's clarifications in their comment, so passers-by don't get caught up in the same confusion. (Although it looks like they beat me to the punch)

Comment: @Giles: Thanks..`perl` worked for me..but with `sed`,i'm getting error: `sed: illegal option -- E`, ,maybe due to different OS..i've `SunOS` system.

Comment: Try my edited sed command